# Javascript setInterval functionality to onmousedown event

Tags: javascript, svg, onmousedown

I am trying to create a Virtual Keyboard using Javascript and an SVG keyboard image.
I have been able to access the `onmousedown` property of a 'button' element and make a call to `myFunction` when that button is pressed.

```
button.onmousedown = (function(self) {
    return function() { self.myFunction(); };
})(this);
```

I was hoping to add a repeat key feature and want to incorporate `setInterval` so that `myFunction` repeats every second or so. I am having trouble incorporating the `setInterval` into the `onmousedown` functionality. Should I try to add `setInterval` to above code or add it to `myFunction`? I want to use just basic Javascript. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I am having trouble incorporating the setInterval" What kind of trouble? What did you try, and what was the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var interval;

button.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
  interval = setInterval(doSomething, 20);
});

button.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
  clearInterval(interval);
});

function doSomething()
{
  //your code here
}
```

Something like this?

Live example: http://cssdeck.com/labs/cbpb6qqm